# Mapbox remove black shapes from map

Tags: android, mapbox

[image]

I use mapbox. What are these black shapes and how to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that only occurs on very specific (usually older) devices. We are tracking the issue on [Github here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5443) and any additional information you can provide to that ticket would be helpful. Right now we haven't been able to reproduce on our end.

Comment: Can I somehow hide them?

Comment: You could create your own style using [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-studio-1/) using none of the icons, but like I mentioned, this only occurs on very specific devices.

Comment: I'm having this issue too on a couple of devices running 4.4. Please let me know if you have found a solution or need any help testing a solution.